# How can I learn the standards(EN,ANSI,ISO) which is related to "roller hemming method in automotive industry"?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, standards, rolling

There is a method using in automotive industry which is called [roller hemming](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hemming_and_seaming).

I have a project about this method but before beginning the project I need to learn the standards(EN,ANSI or ISO) which are related to **roller hemming**.

My question is that *how can I learn what are these standards*. When I read some articles about this method unfortunately I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Check the standards, but for me, this may be more about tooling, processes and material strength.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for your reply, you mean I need to check in those three parts seperately. For example, how can I check for tooling? Is there an easy way to find the standards related with that topic?